# What Design Pattern to use to implement transaction or chaining mechanism

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns

I implemented a simple Factory class in C# and Java. This class builds instances of concrete working classes that have one and the same interface. In particular all these classes have such methods as:

```
create
select
alter
etc.
```

Now I want to have a mechanism (built on top of some classical/non-classical Pattern) that will allow me to create "chains" of these methods or to encapsulate them in a kind of transaction. In a pseudo-code I expect to see something like:

```
Transaction tnx = create(...args...).alter(...args_2...);
//tnx.Execute();
```

Or something like:

```
Transaction tnx;
tnx.Start();
tnx.Add(method_name, ... variable list of arguments ...);
tnx.Add(another_method_name, ... variable list of arguments ...);
tnx.Execute();
```

I'm not that good at design patterns and I'm not sure what pattern to use. I hope someone can share and drop a couple of lines of code (in C# or in Java) that will demonstrate how this can be implemented. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Unit of work* is the right pattern to represent domain transactions.

It accumulates changes (adds, updates and remove) and they can be atomically accepted or discarded. Atomicity is guaranteed by the implementation of the whole unit of work, and the implementer must be sure that changes are persisted or discarded atomically.

Check how Martin Fowler defines it [on his pattern catalog](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html):

> Maintains a list of objects affected by a business transaction and
>   coordinates the writing out of changes and the resolution of
>   concurrency problems.

A possible interface to *Unit of work pattern* could be:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
     void Commit();
     void Rollback();
}
```

And you can also add the following methods to the interface:

```
// Note I've added a generic type parameter to define what kind of
// objects will handle the whole unit of work
public interface IUnitOfWork<TObject>
{
     void RegisterNew(TObject some);
     void RegisterUpdated(TObject some);
     void RegisterDeleted(TObject some);
     void Commit();
     void Rollback();
}
```

Anyway, all updates should be handled using a change tracking monitorized by the unit of work, and some *adds* and *deletes* too:

- If you add a new object to a collection associated to some other object (1-n association), an unit of work should be able to detect that the object is dirty and it should be persisted without manually telling the unit of work to do so.
- Same for removes. If you remove an object from an 1-n association and no other object references it (an orphan object) it should be automatically marked as *deleted*.

Most data mappers like OR/M frameworks already implementing object change tracking using object proxies to intercept property set calls.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds useful! I will check and test this pattern.

Comment: @Jacobian The composite pattern has nothing to do with what you want to solve anyway!

Comment: I guess, you are right. It seems like your advice better suits the task.

Comment: @Jacobian I think so ;P

Answer (score 8):

[Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) is an obvious choice for situations when you model a part-whole system. Here is how the diagram of the pattern looks:

[image: Composite pattern]

Given that you have a factory producing objects of the same interface, you are almost done implementing the composite pattern.

- Your factory produces objects conforming to some interface. This interface is the component interface of your composite implementation.
- Your factory produces concrete classes, which represent the `Leaf` classes in your composite implementation.

The only class left for you to build is the `Composite` class.

Let's say your `Component` interface looks like this:

```
public interface IComponent {
    void Create();
    void Alter();
    void Execute();
}
```

Then your composite class `Transaction` may look like this:

```
public class Transaction : IComponent {
    private readonly IList<IComponent> components = new List<IComponent>();
    public void Add(IComponent c) {
        components.Add(c);
    }
    void Create() {
        foreach (var c in components) {
            c.Create();
        }
    }
    void Alter() {
        foreach (var c in components) {
            c.Alter();
        }
    }
    void Execute() {
        foreach (var c in components) {
            c.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this great masterpiece! I really like it! But may I ask you, please, to demonstrate in a couple of lines of code how it can be used. I'm asking this, because to me it seems like Transaction class is too closely related to concrete classes. Should not it be more decoupled? And by the way what do you think about the Command pattern? Does not it suit the task better than the Composite pattern?

Comment: @Jacobian The purpose of `Transaction` class implementing the same `IComponent` interface as concrete classes is that you can add `Transaction` as a member of another transaction, which may include other transactions itself. `Command` pattern hides the distinction of whole vs. part, but composition is not part of it.

Comment: @Jacobian I also strongly disagree with Matías's unconditional comment that "the composite pattern has nothing to do with what you want to solve anyway", because what you call "transaction" in your description of what you are implementing has little to do with transactions in the atomic-consistent-durable-isolated sense of the word. What you are making looks like a collection of actions, and composite pattern provides a lot of flexibility in the way to implement this.

Comment: I'm not sure, what suits me best. Probably, you are both right and it only depends on the context and concrete tasks implemented in working classes. Thanks!